# Showing this error in my script mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php


session_start();


$hostname="localhost"; //local server name default localhost


$username="root";  //mysql username default is root.


$password="";       //blank if no password is set for mysql.
```

$database="bus-ticket-reservation";  //database name which you created

```
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);


 if(isset($_SESSION['id']))



{


include("config.php");



$uid = $_SESSION['id'];



$bus = $_GET['bus'];


$seat = $_GET['seat'];


$choice = $_GET['choice'];


$bust = $bus.'bus';


$date = date("Y-m-d"); 


 $query = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from bus where id ='$bus'");

 if($query){


    $re1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


        $bus_name = $re1['bus_name'];


        $from = $re1['from_stop'];


        $to = $re1['to_stop'];


        $dept_time = $re1['dept_time'];


        $arrival_time = $re1['arrival_time'];


        $distance = $re1['distance'];


        $fare = $re1['fare'];

}


    if($choice !='')


{


        if($choice=='W' && $seat==1)
{
```

$query2 = "Select * from $bust where status='Available' AND state='$choice' limit 0,$seat";

```
    $p = mysqli_query($con,$query2);


    $re = mysqli_num_rows($p);

        }


    else
        {

   $query2 = "Select * from $bust where status='Available' limit 0,$seat";

   $p = mysqli_query($con,$query2);

   $re = mysqli_num_rows($p);
```

}

```
   if($re>=$seat)
{

     while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($p))
```

{

```
     $id = $r['id'];

      $q3 = mysqli_query($con,"update $bust set status ='Booked' where id='$id'");

         $q4 = mysqli_query($con,"insert into user_history(user_id, bus_id,bus_name, from_stop ,
```

to_stop, booking_date, seat_no_booked, dept_time, distance, fare)

```
 values('".$uid."','".$bus."','".$bus_name."', '".$from."', '".$to."', '".$date."', '".$id."',
```

'".$dept_time."', '".$distance."', '".$fare."')");

```
    }


?>
         <script>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to take this seriously?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams We have upvote the guy who edited it

Comment: Connection Successfull




Notice: Undefined index: in D:\xampp\htdocs\my bus ticket reservation system\booked.php on line 12




Notice: Undefined index: in D:\xampp\htdocs\my bus ticket reservation system\booked.php on line 13




Notice: Undefined index: choice in D:\xampp\htdocs\my bus ticket reservation system\booked.php on line 14




Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in D:\xampp\htdocs\my bus ticket reservation system\booked.php on line 17